# How to use JSON/Object data to make a dynamic Menu/SideNav in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs2

I've this Data that come from the API in a vue component. It looks like this, (Please ignore the syntax mistakes).

```
[
{
id: 1,
name: "Men",
children: [{name: "Tops"}, {name: "Bottom"}]
},
{
id: 2,
name: "Women",
children: [{name: "Tops"}, {name: "Bottom"}]
},
{
id: 3,
name: "Electronics",
children: [{name: "Smart Phone"}, {name: "Feature Phone"}]
},
.
.
.
]
```

What I want is to make a dynamic side navbar menu where first Men, Women and Electronics will be shown. Then If I click on Men, the Tops and Bottoms will be shown. Again if I click on the Electronics the Smart Phone and Feature Phone will be shown. Like in the any eCommerce website's sidenav.

Any idea how can I achieve that using vue js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of dong this is:

- add an extra property `isOpen: false` to every menu item
- then toggle the `isOpen` property by adding a `@click` listener and passing the menu item as argument

  ```
  <div id="side-bar">
      <ul>
          <li v-for="item in menu">
              <div>
                  <h4 @click="toggleChildren(item)">{{item.name}}</h4>
                  <ul v-show="item.isOpen">
                      <li v-for="subItem in item.children">{{subItem.name}}</li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
  ```

**script**

```
new Vue({
    el: '#side-bar',
    data:{
                menu:[
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'Men',
                children: [{name: "Tops"}, {name: "Bottom"}],
                isOpen:false
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'Women',
                children: [{name: "Tops"}, {name: "Bottom"}],
                isOpen:false
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                name: 'Electronics',
                children: [{name: "Smart Phone"}, {name: "Feature Phone"}],
                isOpen:false
            }
        ] 

    },
    methods:{
        toggleChildren(item){
            item.isOpen = !item.isOpen
        }
    }

});
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r_vamsi_krishna/mvsp2ycj/)

Answer (score 1):

use v-for

```js
var example1 = new Vue({
  el: '#example-1',      
  data: {
    items: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Men',
        show: false,
        children: [{name: "Tops"}, {name: "Bottom"}]
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Women',
        show: false,
        children: [{name: "Tops"}, {name: "Bottom"}]
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Electronics',
        show: false,
        children: [{name: "Smart Phone"}, {name: "Feature Phone"}]
      },
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.0/vue.js"></script>

<ul id="example-1">
  <li v-for="item in items" >
    <button v-on:click="item.show = !item.show">
      {{item.name}}
    </button>
    <ul v-if="item.show">
      <li v-for="children in item.children">
        <button>
          {{children.name}}
        </button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I need to show it like a responsive menu.
If I click on the parent element(Men or Women or Electronics) then the child's menu({Tops, Bottom} or {Tops, Bottom} or {Smart Phone, Feature Phone}) will be shown respectively.
A simple iteration won't give me that.